# Extending Entity Framework Model to include new class

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, edmx

Noob question

I'm using Entity Framework in my project, it generates the entities in the designer, like:

```
public partial class CLMEntities : ObjectContext
```

I have another class in the project that I want CLMEntities to inherit from for more functionality:

```
public class MoreFunctionality
```

...of course I can't have that inheritance because it already inherits from `ObjectContext`

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Don't you want to switch to POCOs generation? It supported by both EF 4.x and 5.x (and also both VS2010 and 2012). Then your entity class will inherit no other classes.

Comment: +1  yep get on the new generation templates.   MUCH easier.   The basic tips below from Steve Wilkes still apply... You are just using DBContext instead of ObjectContext. Not sure what design Problem requires a "context" to inherit from custom code.  You can extend partial classes of course.  Including adding different constructors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of options, depending on what the functionality in `MoreFunctionality` is:

1: Make it a generic [decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) class instead of a parent class, like this:

```
public class MoreFunctionality<TEntities> where TEntities : ObjectContext
{
    private readonly TEntities _objectContext;

    public MoreFunctionality(TEntities objectContext)
    {
        this._objectContext = objectContext;
    }

    public TEntities ObjectContext
    {
        get { return this._objectContext; }
    }

    // Other behaviour
}
```

...and pass the decorator around instead of the `ObjectContext`.

2: Make it an interface and add the behaviour using [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx), like this:

```
public interface IMoreFunctionality
{
}

public partial class CLMEntities : ObjectContext, IMoreFunctionality
{
}

public static class MoreFunctionalityExtensions
{
    public static void SomeFunctionality(
        this IMoreFunctionality moreFunctionality)
    {
        // Do something...
    }

    public static void SomeMoreFunctionality(
        this IMoreFunctionality moreFunctionality)
    {
        // Do something else...
    }
}
```

Comment: TNX , in the option 1 if i genrate the edmx again by the genrator it will Changed ?
PLZ you can explian more specific the option 2
thanks alot!

Comment: Option 1 won't be affected by `CLMEntities` being regenerated. Give me an example of the behaviour you have in `MoreFunctionality` and I'll see if I can update my answer using it.